# Replace a word with a bold word using Excel Interop c#

Tags: c#, excel, replace, interop, bold

I am using the following which searches through my entire Excel worksheet and replaces 'req' with 'requirement':

```
oSheet.Cells.Replace("req", "requirement");
```

instead of replacing the word req, I'd like to bold it.  How can I do this?  I know this is wrong, but in theory I'd like to do the following:

```
oSheet.Cells.Replace("req", "<b>req</b>");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to set individual items of text within cells to bold, which is a bit more complicated than first appears. The following will do the trick:

```
    public void FindTextAndSetToBold(string text)
    {
        Excel.Range currentFind = null;
        Excel.Range firstFind = null;

        // Find the first occurrence of the passed-in text

        currentFind = oSheet.Cells.Find(text, Missing.Value, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
            Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
            false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        while (currentFind != null)
        {
            // Keep track of the first range we find

            if (firstFind == null)
            {
                firstFind = currentFind;
            }
            else if (currentFind.get_Address(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value) ==
                firstFind.get_Address(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value))
            {
                // We didn't move to a new range so we're done

                break;
            }

            // We know our text is in first cell of this range, so we need to narrow down its position

            string searchResult = currentFind.get_Range("A1").Value2.ToString();
            int startPos = searchResult.IndexOf(text);

            // Set the text in the cell to bold

            currentFind.get_Range("A1").Characters[startPos + 1, text.Length].Font.Bold = true;

            // Move to the next find

            currentFind = oSheet.Cells.FindNext(currentFind);
        }
    }
```

Taken partly from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and modified.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want? (set beforehand)

```
Application.ReplaceFormat.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
```

Comment: This worked for me jus to make a part of the cell bold.

var range = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex];
range.Value = item.Title + "\r\n" + item.Description;
range.Characters[1, item.Title.Length].Font.Bold = true;